# Javascript/Css matrix3d onscroll function shrinks element when rotating

Tags: javascript, html, css, algorithm, matrix

I am trying to make a function that uses Css matrix3d to transform elements on scroll.  I am using the rematrix library found here [ReMatrix](https://github.com/jlmakes/rematrix) to calculate the matrix then using a percentage progress in the onscroll function to calculate the percentage that the element has moved through the scene.  All of this works fine.

The issue is when rotating the element seems to shrink and then grow back to normal size through the progress of the scene.  Is this the expected behavior of matrix3d?

The some of the initial values in 3dmatrix are 1 so I am accounting for that by adding 1 then subtracting 1.  It works fine for everything except rotation.

Am I missing something in the math here that I am too stupid to figure out it starts and ends on the correct value but shrinks and grows throughout the scene.

Here is an example fiddle and snippet [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/rp95oc4m/26/)

Note: I am just using 700px for scene progress in the demo.  You can ignore the effects after scrolling 700px or when the box rotates past 90deg this is just a demo.

```js
let matrix;
const el = document.querySelector('.box');

const updateScroll = () => {

  const scrollPos = window.scrollY;
  const progress = scrollPos / 700;
  
  let m = [...matrix];
  m[0] = progress * (matrix[0] - 1) + 1;
  m[1] = progress * matrix[1];
  m[2] = progress * matrix[2];
  m[3] = progress * matrix[3];
  m[4] = progress * matrix[4];
  m[5] = progress * (matrix[5] - 1) + 1;
  m[6] = progress * matrix[6];
  m[7] = progress * matrix[7];
  m[8] = progress * matrix[8];
  m[9] = progress * matrix[9];
  m[10] = progress * (matrix[10] - 1) + 1;
  m[11] = progress * matrix[11];
  m[12] = progress * (matrix[12] / 100) * 100;
  m[13] = progress * (matrix[13] / 100) * 100;
  m[14] = progress * (matrix[14] / 100) * 100;
  m[15] = progress * (matrix[15] - 1) + 1;
  
  setTransform(el, toString(m));
}

const init = () => {
  const r1 = rotateZ(90);
  const t1 = translateY(700);
  matrix = multiply(t1,r1);
  window.addEventListener('scroll', updateScroll);
}

const setTransform = (el, transform) => {
  el.style.transform = transform;
  el.style.WebkitTransform = transform;
};

/*
*  
* REMATRIX Functions
* https://github.com/jlmakes/rematrix
*
*/


function translateY(distance) {
  const matrix = identity();
  matrix[13] = distance;
  return matrix;
}

function toString(source) {
  return `matrix3d(${format(source).join(', ')})`;
}

function rotateZ(angle) {
  const theta = (Math.PI / 180) * angle;
  const matrix = identity();

  matrix[0] = matrix[5] = Math.cos(theta).toFixed(6);
  matrix[1] = matrix[4] = Math.sin(theta).toFixed(6);
  matrix[4] *= -1;

  return matrix;
}

function format(source) {
  if (source.constructor !== Array) {
    throw new TypeError('Expected array.');
  }
  if (source.length === 16) {
    return source;
  }
  if (source.length === 6) {
    const matrix = identity();
    matrix[0] = source[0];
    matrix[1] = source[1];
    matrix[4] = source[2];
    matrix[5] = source[3];
    matrix[12] = source[4];
    matrix[13] = source[5];
    return matrix;
  }
  throw new RangeError('Expected array with either 6 or 16 values.');
}

function identity() {
  const matrix = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    i % 5 == 0 ? matrix.push(1) : matrix.push(0);
  }
  return matrix;
}

function multiply(m, x) {
  const fm = format(m);
  const fx = format(x);
  const product = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    const row = [fm[i], fm[i + 4], fm[i + 8], fm[i + 12]];
    for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      const k = j * 4;
      const col = [fx[k], fx[k + 1], fx[k + 2], fx[k + 3]];
      const result =
        row[0] * col[0] + row[1] * col[1] + row[2] * col[2] + row[3] * col[3];

      product[i + k] = result;
    }
  }

  return product;
}

init();
```

```css
body{
  min-height: 400vh;
}

.box{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Anyone help here would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure to understand what you are doing... What is this `m[0] = progress * (matrix[0] - 1) + 1; m[1]...` supposed to do? Are you expecting these to do the transformations? I may miss something, but you already have a lot of functions that do just these, correctly. If what you want is to rotate and translate your element, then create a new matrix like you did in `init` every time: https://jsfiddle.net/bvxudwn0/

Comment: @Kaiido `m[0] = progress * (matrix[0] - 1) + 1;` is supposed to go from a zero transform to the final transform value throughout the progress.  I was trying to make a function that would encompass all of the values in the matrix3d depending on what is set.  Which works except for all scale, skew, translate, just not for rotate.  I now see that more values change in the matrix along the way with rotate than are set in the initial and final matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matrix rotation is not just a linear interpolation of the values.

You already have a correct implementation of single axis rotation, implying modifying both the scale and skew values:

```
function rotateZ(angle) {
  const theta = (Math.PI / 180) * angle;
  const matrix = identity();

  matrix[0] = matrix[5] = Math.cos(theta).toFixed(6);
  matrix[1] = matrix[4] = Math.sin(theta).toFixed(6);
  matrix[4] *= -1;

  return matrix;
}
```

So your algebra is all broken there, which will mess up the scale values and will shrink your element.

But you already have all you need, just use it.

```js
const el = document.querySelector('.box');

const updateScroll = () => {

  const scrollPos = window.scrollY;
  const progress = Math.min(scrollPos / 700, 1);
  // create a new Matrix, correctly translated and rotated
  const t1 = translateY(scrollPos);
  const r1 = rotateZ( 360 * progress );
  const matrix = multiply(t1, r1);
  setTransform(el, toString(matrix));
}

const init = () => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', updateScroll);
}

const setTransform = (el, transform) => {
  el.style.transform = transform;
  el.style.WebkitTransform = transform;
};

/*
*  
* REMATRIX Functions
* https://github.com/jlmakes/rematrix
*
*/


function translateY(distance) {
  const matrix = identity();
  matrix[13] = distance;
  return matrix;
}

function toString(source) {
  return `matrix3d(${format(source).join(', ')})`;
}

function rotateZ(angle) {
  const theta = (Math.PI / 180) * angle;
  const matrix = identity();

  matrix[0] = matrix[5] = Math.cos(theta).toFixed(6);
  matrix[1] = matrix[4] = Math.sin(theta).toFixed(6);
  matrix[4] *= -1;

  return matrix;
}

function format(source) {
  if (source.constructor !== Array) {
    throw new TypeError('Expected array.');
  }
  if (source.length === 16) {
    return source;
  }
  if (source.length === 6) {
    const matrix = identity();
    matrix[0] = source[0];
    matrix[1] = source[1];
    matrix[4] = source[2];
    matrix[5] = source[3];
    matrix[12] = source[4];
    matrix[13] = source[5];
    return matrix;
  }
  throw new RangeError('Expected array with either 6 or 16 values.');
}

function identity() {
  const matrix = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    i % 5 == 0 ? matrix.push(1) : matrix.push(0);
  }
  return matrix;
}

function multiply(m, x) {
  const fm = format(m);
  const fx = format(x);
  const product = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    const row = [fm[i], fm[i + 4], fm[i + 8], fm[i + 12]];
    for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      const k = j * 4;
      const col = [fx[k], fx[k + 1], fx[k + 2], fx[k + 3]];
      const result =
        row[0] * col[0] + row[1] * col[1] + row[2] * col[2] + row[3] * col[3];

      product[i + k] = result;
    }
  }

  return product;
}

init();
```

```css
body{
  height: 400vh;
  min-height: 700px;
}

.box{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```